# AMPScript to create a contact in salesforce with validation rule

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have a validation rule on creating contacts which forces the Account Name to be set.  When creating the Contact using AMPScript how do I set the Account to be the value I want?  (This can be a hard coded Account as we only use one).

I have tried setting the AccountId but this doesnt get past the validation rule.

```
CreateSalesforceObject("Contact",8,"FirstName",@firstName,"LastName",@lastName,"Email",@email,"Gender__c",@gender,"MobilePhone",@mobile,"Recieve_HTML_Emails__c",@emailTxtImage,"Receive_Text_Emails__c",@emailTxt,"Receive_SMS__c",@sms,"AccountId","TESTID")
```

Tried setting Account to TEST even though this is not a field on contact record.

```
CreateSalesforceObject("Contact",8,"FirstName",@firstName,"LastName",@lastName,"Email",@email,"Gender__c",@gender,"MobilePhone",@mobile,"Recieve_HTML_Emails__c",@emailTxtImage,"Receive_Text_Emails__c",@emailTxt,"Receive_SMS__c",@sms,"Account.Name","TEST")
```

Here is the validation Rule

```
Account.Name <> "TEST"
```

I have also tried changing the Validation Rule to be on the AccountId but this doesnt work when saving the contact through Salesforce.

Any help appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

School boy error, number of fields updated was 9 not 8, so the parameter in question was being missed. Changing it to 9 meant that using the AccountId worked.

Thanks